# trying to combine items and find the average

Tags: sql, average

I am trying to combine like opods and like dpods and find the average final_nr for each of these combinations.

```
select column_1, column_2, Column_3, final, cust_name
From big2
Where q_date > '2017-1-1'
and cust_name = 'XYZ, LLC'
and setup = 1

should look like 
Column_1  Column_2 Column_3  final  customer name 
    a         b       3       $50        XYZ
    a         c       2       $45        XYZ
    c         d       5       $55        XYZ
```

Comment: Use group by Opod ,Dpod

Comment: Question is not clear ... elaborate it little more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query-:

```
select Opod, Dpod, finlocked,avg(final_nr), cust_name
From analytics..ig_uly2
Where quote_date > '2017-1-1'
and cust_name = 'XYZ, LLC'
and setup = 1
group by Opod, Dpod, finlocked, cust_name
```

SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

just use `group by` and `avg` aggregate function
and use `in` clause as you consider two customer name

```
    select Opod, Dpod, finlocked, avg(final_nr) as avgfinal, cust_name
    From analytics..ig_uly2
    Where quote_date > '2017-01-01'
    and cust_name in( 'XYZ', 'LLC')
    and setup = 1
    group by  Opod, Dpod, finlocked,cust_name
```